# How to input additional parameter to onMouseDown function in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The function is as below written in `TypeScript`:

```js
const handleMouseDownHome = (e: any) => {
    // Only works if the scroll mouse button is clicked
    if (e.button === 1) {
      window.open("/", "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
    }
};

<div onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
    ...
</div>
```

The `url` that is being used above is `"/"` and I would like to pass the `url` as a parameter so the function would be dynamic. Expected function:

```js
const handleMouseDownHome = (e: any, url: any) => {
    // Only works if the scroll mouse button is clicked
    if (e.button === 1) {
      window.open(url, "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
    }
};

<div onMouseDown={<What to Modify Here>}>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Since `handleMouseDownHome` already has the event ("e"), and thus also has e.currentTarget, you can add `data-url={"YOUR_URL_HERE"}` to the div and then access it in `handleMouseDownHome` with `e.currentTarget.dataset.url`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you mean is you want to pass a URL when **setting up** the handler, you can curry the function. To do this, you make a function that takes a parameter and returns another function that uses that parameter.

```
function handleMouseDown(url) {
  return function(e){
     if (e.button === 1) {
      window.open("/", "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a working react example, but it logs the url to the console.

```js
function App(){
  const handleMouseDown = url => e => {
    if (e.button === 1) console.log(url)
  }
  const url = 'www.google.com';
  
  return <button onMouseDown={handleMouseDown(url)}>Middle Click Me</button>
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

If instead, you want to have a variable that can get set by other functions and then be used by the handler, then you don't need to pass it, it just needs to be accessible by the function, as in, in its lexical scope.

Since the variable is assumed to be changing, we should use a state:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App(){
  const [url, setURL] = useState('');
  
  const handleMouseDown = e => {
    if (e.button === 1) console.log(url)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
    <input onChange={(e)=> setURL(e.target.value)}></input>
    <button className='click' onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>Middle Click Me</button>
  </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```